# Nextcord Ban & Kick issue

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py, bots, nextcord

I'm trying to make a discord.py bot with the help of nextcord and i've come far enough to make the code work in theory but nothing happens when i try to kick / ban, it just throws an

*nextcord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'ban'*

and i have no idea why it does so, i want it to work as inteded.

*Note, the command(s) are class commands so the main bot loads in the command from another file.*

**Main Bot Script**

```
# import nextcord
from nextcord.ext import commands
# import asyncio
import json

# Import all of the commands
from cogs.ban import ban
from cogs.hello import hello
from cogs.help import help
from cogs.info import info
from cogs.kick import kick
from cogs.test import test

#Define bot prefix and also remove the help command built in.
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=json.load(open("config.json"))["prefix"])
bot.remove_command("help")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user}')

bot.add_cog(hello(bot))
bot.add_cog(help(bot))
bot.add_cog(info(bot))
bot.add_cog(test(bot))
bot.add_cog(ban(bot))
bot.add_cog(kick(bot))

bot.run(json.load(open("config.json"))["token"])
```

**Problematic command**

```
import discord
from nextcord.ext import commands
from nextcord.ext.commands import has_permissions, CheckFailure

bot = commands.bot

class ban(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
        self._last_member = None
    
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('ban Cog Ready')

    @commands.command()
    @has_permissions(ban_members=True)
    async def ban(ctx, user: discord.Member = None, *, Reason = None):
        if user == None:
            await ctx.send("Could you please enter a valid user?")
            return

        try:
            await user.ban(reason=Reason)
            await ctx.send(f'**{0}** has been banned.'.format(str(user)))
        except Exception as error:
            if isinstance(error, CheckFailure):
                await ctx.send("Looks like you don't have the permissions to use this command.")
            else:
                await ctx.send(error)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing:

```
user: discord.Member
```

You need to use nextcord instead.

```
user: nextcord.Member
```

```
    @commands.command()
    @has_permissions(ban_members=True)
    async def ban(ctx, user: nextcord.Member = None, *, Reason = None):#
        #The rest of your code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, here are the problems:

- Your command is in a cog therefore you need to say `(self, ctx, and so on)`
- You need to change the `discord` to `nextcord`
- You should change the `commands.bot` to `commands.Bot()`
- And if I'm correct, you should change the `self.client` to `self.bot` since your `commands.Bot()` is defined as `bot`

And uhh yeah it should work perfectly after you fix those.

Answer (score 0):

**You can do the following**

*For Normal bot*

```
@client.command(name="ban", aliases=["modbancmd"], description="Bans the mentioned user.")
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(self, ctx, member: nextcord.Member, *, reason=None):
    # Code for embed (optional)
    await member.ban(reason=reason)
    # (optional) await ctx.send(embed=banembed)
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can do the following**

*For Cogs*

```
@commands.command(name="ban", aliases=["modbancmd"], description="Bans the mentioned user.")
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(self, ctx, member: nextcord.Member, *, reason=None):
    # Code for embed (optional)
    await member.ban(reason=reason)
    # (optional) await ctx.send(embed=banembed)
```